# PHP : Simple DOM Parser how to iterate html code

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<div class="reviews-summary__stats">
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">C</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">C</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">C</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>     
</div>
```

i want to iterate over each **div.reviews-summary** but i am not getting to next **p.reviews-title** and **li.rating__item rating__rated** tag, also count **li.rating__item rating__rated** for display **li.rating__item rating__rated** in  integer.

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $obj = new simple_html_dom();

    foreach ($obj->find('div[class=reviews-summary]') as $factor)
    {
        $item = $factor->find('p[class=reviews-title]')->plaintext;

        if(trim($item) == 'A')
        { 
            $a = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        if(trim($item) == 'B')
        { 
            $b = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        if(trim($item) == 'C')
        { 
            $c = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        $final_array['overalldata'] = array
        (
            'a' => $a,   // no of A have <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li> 
            'b' => $b,
            'c' => $c,
        );
    }
    print_r($final_array);
    die;
?>
```

i want display like this type of output, 
 **Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3

            [b] => 4

            [c] => 2

        )
)**
and also count the `li.rating__item rating__rated` it, and display integer value of no of **li.rating__item rating__rated** are exist in list

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: Where do you load the HTML?

Comment: Take a look on [PHP DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes, but have included a couple of versions as they both format the data differently.  I think the main problem was that when you use `find()`, this may return a list of items found and so when setting `$a` etc. you had used the second parameter to pick out the `plaintext` of the first item (using `,0`), you didn't do this when looking for the `$item` value.  So I've added the same to this call.

```
$final_array=array();
foreach ($obj->find('div[class=reviews-summary]') as $factor)
{
    $item = $factor->find('p[class=reviews-title]',0)->plaintext;
    if(trim($item) == 'A')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['a'] = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
    }
    if(trim($item) == 'B')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['b'] = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
    }
    if(trim($item) == 'C')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['c'] = $factor->find('li[class="rating__item rating__rated"]',0)->plaintext;
    }
}
print_r($final_array);
```

This gives (with your sample data)...

```
Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [c] => 
        )

)
```

Alternatively...

```
$final_array=array();
foreach ($obj->find('div[class=reviews-summary]') as $factor)
{
    $a = null;
    $b = null;
    $c = null;
    $item = trim($factor->find('p[class=reviews-title]',0)->plaintext);
    $factor = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]');
    $count = count($factor);
    if($item == 'A')
    {
        $a = $factor[0]->plaintext;
    }
    if($item == 'B')
    {
        $b = $factor[0]->plaintext;
    }
    if($item == 'C')
    {
        $c = $factor[0]->plaintext;
    }
    $final_array['overalldata'] = array
    (
        'a' => $a,
        'b' => $b,
        'c' => $c,
        'count' =>$count
    );
}
print_r($final_array);
```

With a slightly altered set of test data gives...

```
Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 
            [b] => 
            [c] => Some content
        )

)
```

**Update:**

I've updated the second example, I've moved some of the common code into the main part.  The `$count` is just the number of `<li class="rating__item rating__rated">` items (I think this is what your asking for).

Comment: thank u @nigel ren, small issue solve bt i also count the li[class=rating__item rating__rated] to display rated

Comment: Sorry - not sure what you mean by the second part.

Comment: i display like this type of output,                                                     
Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4 
            [b] => 4
            [c] => 4   
        )
)                                                                                                                      and also if li.rating__item rating__rated then count it, and display integer value of no of li.rating__item rating__rated are exist in list

Comment: I've change the second code example, have a look if that is helpful.

Comment: solution please:) @nigel ren